# Adobe PDF Forms Javascript, sum values from different fields

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a PDF form with lots of different fields and different summarizations for those fields. To solve it I have named the different fields A_1, A_2 and so on and B_1, B_2 and so on. Then I created a loop that extracts the values from the fields and pushes them to an array. In the end the area is summarized in the output field.

The code as it looks today:

```
var numbers = [];

for(var i=1; i < 11; i++){    
   x = getField("A_"+i).value;
   numbers.push(x);
}

function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
}
event.value = numbers.reduce(getSum);
```

Works great. But with my current code I have to define the end number of fields, in this case A_10. But I would like it to go on until it finds a field that doesn´t exist. My current solution requires that I know how many fields there are and I´d like to get away from that. Any suggestions?

Comment: could you show us getField?

Comment: Not very familiary with Adobe forms, but could you check inside your `for` loop to see if `getField("A_"+i).value` exists?  or maybe just if `getField("A_"+i)` exists?

Comment: getField is a built in function, it just gets the text fields and collects the data from them.

Comment: so if a field is empty or not used, it won't return `undefined`?  just null or 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript isn't actually required for this. A far easier approach would be to name your fields hierarchically. Acrobat will create an array of fields if you name them A.1, A.2, A.3 etc. "A" then becomes the parent and you can get the sum of all of the "A" children regardless of how many there are through the Acrobat UI. Just go into the total field, select the "calculate" tab, select "sum", and then "Pick" A.

[image]

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple. Thanks a lot!